# Installing hermes-engine (0.71.2) got stuck react native

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-hermes, pod-install

I have created a new react native project and then install npm , run command bundle install and then then cd iOS pod install but it got stuck on

```
Installing React-perflogger (0.71.2)
Installing React-runtimeexecutor (0.71.2)
Installing ReactCommon (0.71.2)
Installing SocketRocket (0.6.0)
Installing TOCropViewController (2.6.1)
Installing Yoga (1.14.0)
Installing YogaKit (1.18.1)
Installing boost (1.76.0)
Installing fmt (6.2.1)
Installing glog (0.3.5)
Installing hermes-engine (0.71.2)
```

here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "ApproverApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.16.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.5.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.0",
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "css-to-react-native": "^3.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mime": "^3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "native-base": "^3.3.7",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.2",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1279.0",
    "react-native-date-picker": "^4.2.0",
    "react-native-dialog": "^9.2.1",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^8.0.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.37.3",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-popup-menu": "^0.15.12",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native-responsive-fontsize": "^0.5.1",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.1.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.13.1",
    "react-native-size-matters": "^0.4.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.3.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "^3.2.9",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.2.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.73.7",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

actually may be it is not stuck.
Try `cd ios && pod install --verbose` for more info.
As shown as below, it will show time consume info while download.
In my case, it use 45 minutes to download and install `hermes-engine (0.71.4)`. Very very slow....

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
```

Answer (score 5):

Most of time the issue is due to a slow internet connection.

I was creating a new project via internet connection 1 at home and it always got stuck Installing hermes-engine (0.71.2). However, when
I moved to another internet connection 2 at the office then it took 5 minutes to create a new project via the command `npx react-native init mynewawesomeproject`.

As @kyo-kurosagi mentioned in their answer try this so you can check the progress. It may take up to 40 minutes to an hour to download and install. `pod install --verbose`

Comment: If we can download `hermes-engine` from VPN much more quickly, then how can we make it as a local cache?

Comment: Same I was on 2.5GHz network after switching to 5GHz network it was very fast

Answer (score 4):

I have managed to fix this problem by following the instructions in [this comment](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34608#issuecomment-1319114711).

So basically what you have to do:

1. Install the version of Ruby listed in the `Gemfile` and `.ruby-version`. You can use http://rbenv.org/ or https://rvm.io/ to install and use the version from the `.ruby-version` file. [Here are the instructions for `rbenv`](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#how-it-works)
2. Install correct version of `CocoaPods` using `bundle install`
3. Update the CocoaPods repo using `bundle exec pod repo update`
4. Install pods by `cd`-ing into the `ios` folder `cd ios` and then run `bundle exec pod install`

Comment: I get the following error: `The requested URL returned error: 403`. So I don't think my issue is ruby or gem related. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 3):

You need to clean and re-install your pods:

1 - `sudo gem install cocoapods-clean`

2 - `pod deintegrate`

3 - `pod clean` ( this is no longer available )

4 - `sudo pod install --allow-root`

Answer (score 2):

If you're using ARM-based chip try this: `arch -arm64 npx react-native init ProjectName`

Answer (score 2):

using `arch -arm64 npx react-native init` works perfectly in mac m1

Comment: It helps readability to put command line calls in back-ticks which formats the content to look more like code (fixed-width characters, different background).

Comment: This is essentially just an inferior copy of this answer above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75500604/7943564

Answer (score 1):

I had tried the same, I was thinking that my simulator got stuck. I stopped installing pods and again run pods install command and see it was again taking time. It's not a stuck issue. It'll take some time for installing this specific pod.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moTtW.png)